# Работа InputMethodListener

Tags: java, swing

Работаю с java.swing и не могу никак понять какое назначение следующих слушателей

```
searchField.addInputMethodListener(new InputMethodListener() {
        @Override
        public void inputMethodTextChanged(InputMethodEvent event) {
        }
        @Override
        public void caretPositionChanged(InputMethodEvent event) {
        }
```

searchField - JTextField

Сначала думал что эти слушатели работают когда изменяется текст в соответствующем поле, но как оказалось это не так. Смотрел документацию данных слушателей, но так и не понял что они делают. Буду благодарен за объяснение.

Comment: А что не понял?

Comment: На что именно реагируют эти слушатели

Comment: Первый - если вы произвели изменения в тексте. Второй - если перешли на новую строку

Comment: Но ведь я проверял, даже самым примитивным методом, добавлял единственную функцию в первый слушатель, неодноразово менял текст в поле, а он не работал